# Writing text from right in same line in JQMobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I am using this code to display line like this        ***1234        :order**                                                        .....................................................................***some text*** (wihtout all the ......)

```
            <ul data-role="listview" class="test" data-theme="a">
        <li>
<div class="ui-grid-a" data-theme="a">
<div class="ui-block-a"></div>
<div class="ui-block-b">1234</div>

</div>
            <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>order</strong></p> 
        </li>  
        <li><div class="ui-block">some text(not english)</div></li>    

    </ul>
```

Now I want to dipslay another line that will start from the right side and woudld be displayed on all the raw without creating new `li`.(from right to left) if i do it with another `li`so i am getting another list, How can i do it on the same line without starting new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "if i do it with another liso i am getting another list", but using another `<li>` makes a lot of sense.

Just giv this li a class (lets say class="fr") and then in the css do:

```
.fr{
float: right;
text-align: right
}
```

Comment: yes but the result will be 2 rows with border between them, i want it be in one row.

Comment: This is just a styling issue, you can solve it by using floats.